# /var/log/auth.log not logging failed ssh attempts

Tags: authentication, logging, ssh

I'm trying to go failed (either incorrect username, password, or both) on my server.

I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config from

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH 
LogLevel INFO
```

to

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH 
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

and have since tried multiple ssh attempts with both existing and non-exisiting users with random passwords thus failing. When checking /var/log/auth.log nothing appears and it is entirely blank.

What am I missing? Does some other process need to also be install and running on my system? I'm running Ubuntu.

Any help or guidance on this matter is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This question is best suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need a system logger. Some distributions ship with `syslog-ng` now days which is a complex, but flexible service for logging. It should be noted that the minimum configuration to get the described effect is not that complex:

```
   source src {
       unix-stream("/dev/log");
       internal();
   };
   source kernsrc {
       file("/proc/kmsg");
   };

   destination authlog { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
   filter f_authpriv { facility(auth, authpriv); };
   log { source(src); filter(f_authpriv); destination(authlog); };
```

According to the Ubuntu community wiki, the default logging daemon is not syslog-ng in Ubuntu and the [configuration file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Configuration_of_syslogd) format is not as in the example above. I suggest you consider both options and pick the one which suits your needs.

After making the decision, you will need to run the logger service. Use either the `service` binary or run the script in /etc/init.d with the start argument. Look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services) for hints.

Comment: Brilliant. I installed syslog-ng `sudo apt-get install syslog-ng` and the defaults were enough. I have also installed sshguard with it. Thanks for your help :-)